# In linux for a running java process, how to find its parameters, such as its debug port?

Tags: java, linux

I have a running java process, I want to find out with which parameters it was started, specifically, I want to know what debug port was specified (it was). Is there a way to do that in linux?

Update: Application was started through ant, so I can get ant command options, so now I know the task that was started, also I know ant process id.

Comment: I use `jps -lvm` to get its command line arguments.

Comment: jps doesn't show that. application was started through ant.

Comment: It shouldn't matter how it was started, if it's running in debug mode it has to have the appropriate options on the command line.

Comment: http://garyes.stormloader.com/its.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `ps -fe` ?

From the `ps` man page

> -f              Do full-format listing. This option can be combined
>   with many other UNIX-style options to add additional columns. **It also
>                          causes the command arguments to be printed**. When used with -L, the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID)
>   columns
>                          will be added. See the c option, the format keyword args, and the format keyword comm.

(my emphasis)

Comment: you can also add a pipe grep <appname> to limit the results. `ps -ef | grep YourAppName` or sometimes `ps -ef | grep java` is enough

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I found process I was looking for. The trick was that at first I should find id of the ant process and then look in ps -fe for it's child processes.

Answer (score 7):

`jps -v -m` might help also you can `cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline`

EDIT: `jvisualvm` provide also a bunch of infos about running java processes.